# Relation of two definitions of 'Singular Point'

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

In my lecture we defined:

> For $(a,b)=P\in V(f)$, $P$ is a *singular point* if $\operatorname{mult}(f,P)>1$, where $\operatorname{mult}(f,P) = \max\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid f\in\mathfrak{m}_P^{n}\}$, and $\mathfrak{m}_{P}=(x-a,y-b)$.  ($f\in k[X,Y]\setminus k$, $P\in\mathbb{A}^2$).

Now in Shafarevich's 'Basic Algebraic Geometry' he defined:

> Let $C=V(f)$ be a curve. $P$ is a *singular point* of $C$, if $f_x '(P)=f_y'(P)=f(P)=0$.

I don't see how these two definitions are the same. It would be really nice if someone could explain me how these two definitions are connected. Thanks and best, Luca!

Comment: Take the Taylor series expansion of $f$ around $P$. Then $mult(f,P)$, according to your first definition, is the smallest degree of a nonzero term in that expansion. (Do you see why?) In partcular it is nonzero iff the linear part is zero, ie iff the coefficients of $x-a$ and $y-b$ are zero. But those coefficients are precisely the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$.

Comment: hm. really? because my professor wrote it in the lecture like this. Do you maybe mean the minimum of where $f\not\in \mathfrak{m}_P^{n}$?

Comment: But we had the following example in class (with the 1st definition): $f = y-x²$, $P=(0,0)\Rightarrow \mathfrak{m}_P = (x,y)$, so $f\in\mathfrak{m}_P$, but $f\not\in\mathfrak{m}_P^{2}=(x^2,xy,y^2)$. So $mult(f,P)=1$. And another example: $f=y^2-x^3-x^2$, $P=(0,0)\Rightarrow f\in\mathfrak{m}=(x,y), f\in\mathfrak{m}^2, f\not\in\mathfrak{m}^3$, so $mult(f,P)=2$. With the minimum it would be 1 no?

Comment: Dear @Luca, I typed faster than I thought. Sorry for the confusion!